# changing JAVA_OPTIONS value from -Xmx512M to -Xmx1024M

Tags: eclipse, out-of-memory, heap-size

changing environment variable JAVA_OPTIONS value from -Xmx512M to -Xmx1024M didnt work. When I build my code in eclipse, it still says "Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx512M". 
I even put -Xmx1024M in the program argument and VM argument at run configuration.

Can someone tell why it is still picking up -Xmx512M? is there any other changes i need to make?

Comment: Have you set it in the eclipse config file?

Answer (score 2):

You have to set in `eclipse.ini` file after `-vmargs`:

```
-Xms512m
-Xmx1024m
```

Comment: ok one more question, i set max size to -xmx2048m but its picking up 1024m only.. is it because thats the max size supported by my eclipse? or does it depend on RAM size 4GB and system type 32 bit OS ?

Comment: Wait, with Xmx you define the MAXIMUM heap size (so your application will take up to 2048m before start swapping/garbage collecting like crazy/throwing an out of memory exception), with Xms you define the memory allocated at application start. By the way, the max heap size on a 32bit machine is around 4 GB.